# Win XP bootup error after increasing virtual hdd size in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I increased virtual hdd size using `VBoxManage modifyhd ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/XP/XP.vdi --resize 30000`. Now I wanted to start XP to get it to accept the new size but I can't boot. Error is: NTLDR is missing. I don't have a deep enough knowledge of VirtualBox to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would try, but it's merely a hypothetical answer, so backup your virual machine if you decide to try this. By backup I mean create a duplicate of your VM folder.

step # 1 = attach a second virtual hard drive to the virtual machine

Step #2 = Attach an ubuntu iso to the virtual machine boot into it and use the default archive tool to create a .zip backup of your Windows XP partition including hidden files.

Step #2 = Create a new partition table (mbr style) on both virtual hard drives using gparted or disks in ubuntu live cd then create a partition on each drive using the same filesystem as your previous XP install was (most likely NTFS).

Step #3 = Save the .zip of your xp install to the second hard drive

Step #4 = re-install xp with your xp installation disc, or download one from here:

Windows XP - Professional SP3 X86-32:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/e/9/ee9d0116-c9fe-4fc2-b59c-406cbfb6d515/xpsp3_5512.080413-2113_usa_x86fre_spcd.iso

Step #5 = attach the ubuntu iso again, using disks or gparted format the windows xp installation you just did, don't delete the partition just re-format it.

Step #6 = extract the .zip you made of your old xp install onto the newly formated drive

The idea behind this is that the installation disc setups up the drive for use in terms of bootloader etc and .zip deploys the old install much like imagex or dism would deploy a .wim file.